# Unity setting Player Settings Target Architectures via Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have my custom build script and I want to add more options in it.
One of them is Target Architectures. (I'm using IL2CPP as a scripting backend - I set it by script)

Here you can see which settings I want to change:
[image]

According to [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerSettings.SetArchitecture.html) I can use PlayerSettings.SetArchitecture(), but it seems not to work for me at all. It only has an option for 0 - None, 1 - ARM64, 2 - Universal and I want All. So I tried using:

```
PlayerSettings.SetArchitecture(BuildTargetGroup.Android, unchecked((int)AndroidArchitecture.All));
```

but it doesn't change anything, also the lines below does not change anything:

```
PlayerSettings.SetArchitecture(BuildTargetGroup.Android, unchecked((int)AndroidArchitecture.ARM64));
PlayerSettings.SetArchitecture(BuildTargetGroup.Android, unchecked((int)AndroidArchitecture.ARMv7));
PlayerSettings.SetArchitecture(BuildTargetGroup.Android, unchecked((int)AndroidArchitecture.X86));
```

I'm wondering how I can do it correctly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The second parameter of the `PlayerSettings.SetArchitecture` function expects `0` for None, `1` for ARM64 and `2` for Universal. This is **not** what you are really looking for.

---

With the screenshot in your question, you are looking for the [`PlayerSettings.Android.targetArchitectures`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerSettings.Android-targetArchitectures.html) property which can be used to set ARM64, ARMv7 or X86 as the build architecture with the [`AndroidArchitecture`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidArchitecture.html) enum.

To set only one architecture:

```
PlayerSettings.Android.targetArchitectures = AndroidArchitecture.X86;
```

---

To set only **multiple** architecture, use enum flags since `AndroidArchitecture` is declared with the `Flags` attribute which allows the bitwise manipulations to be used to select multiple values:

```
AndroidArchitecture aac = AndroidArchitecture.ARM64 | AndroidArchitecture.ARMv7 | AndroidArchitecture.X86;
PlayerSettings.Android.targetArchitectures = aac;
```

or

```
AndroidArchitecture aac = AndroidArchitecture.ARM64;
aac |= AndroidArchitecture.ARMv7;
aac |= AndroidArchitecture.X86;   
PlayerSettings.Android.targetArchitectures = aac;
```

You can learn more about enum flags [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/what-does-the-flags-enum-attribute-mean-in-c).

If you just want to use all the architectures then simply use `AndroidArchitecture.All`.

```
PlayerSettings.Android.targetArchitectures = AndroidArchitecture.All;
```